# Installing matplotlib under Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to install matplotlib under Windows Vista. Both python itself and numpy are working for me.

I installed matplotlib via the executable `basemap-1.0.2.win32-py2.7` and followed the [official instructions](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#installing-on-windows). But running `from matplotlib import *` gives me the following error:

`No module named matplotlib`

Any ideas how to get matplotlib working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

basemap is not the installer for matplotlib.
basemap is a library of the matplotlib toolkit for plotting 2D data on maps, you need to indepently install matplotlib to use it.

You can get matplotlib from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/)

Comment: And to update MPL on windows, see http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html (bottom of the page).

Answer (score 16):

you can install by `pip install matplotlib`

Make sure that you already installed `setuptools, numpy, python-dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, and cycler` before that.

Comment: hi, I installed all the tools you listed from `setuptools` to `cycler` and then I did `pip install matplotlib` but I get this error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1`. Any ideas?

Comment: I executed `pip install --upgrade setuptools` from a command prompt with administrator rights and after that `pip install matplotlib` worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import *
```

This works on a proper the default scipy/pylab/matplotlib setup. And to get you started:

```
> hist(randn(10000)) 
> show()
```

Matplotlib is a part of the [pylab suite](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing matplotlib under windows using anaconda. Here are the steps..

I am using Anaconda 1.8.7

1. Goto your Anaconda Navigator and choose Environments
2. Click on the arrow and choose Open terminal
3. Type conda install matplotlib

That should do the trick. For specific versions and to install onto specific environments within annaconda you can utilise the = and -n / name option

https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html 
[Matplotlib Installation using command prompt / Annaconda Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiVyr.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Open Command Prompt

C:\Users\Uname>python -m pip install matplotlib

Matplotlib requires some of the following dependencies:

FreeType libpng NumPy setuptools cycler dateutil kiwisolver pyparsing